# is there any difference in these two code snippets ? if so how please explain

Tags: c

what is the difference between these two code snippets please can someone explain?

```
int a [ 7 ] ;
```

and

```
int *a = malloc ( sizeof ( int ) * 7 ) ;
```

?

I am a beginner in coding and I have no idea and I have tried to search it in online but couldn't find

Comment: The first snippet has an array; the 2nd has a pointer. Arrays and pointers are different, see section 6 of [the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The first one will allocate memory to `a` at compile time generally on stack, while second one will allocate memory in run time(generally heap) that is when you execute program.

Typically, you don't have to free memory that is allocated statically, but when you allocate memory dynamically(at run time), you should `free` it after using it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet you are allocating memory for an array of 7 integers. This memory is contiguous and taken from the stack at compile time.

In the second snippet, we have allocated memory from the heap. Again of 7 integers and the pointer variable 'a' points to this block of memory.

Note that the memory allocated for both of them is same. Also, we sometimes say that an array has decayed into a pointer. To say simply, array names in a C program are (in most cases) converted to pointers. One exception is when we use the sizeof operator on an array. If a was converted to a pointer in this context, sizeof a would give the size of a pointer and not of the actual array, which would be rather useless, so in that case a means the array itself.